# Finding the largest X/Y/Z component of an orbit (in terms of ECI) using orbital elements?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements

If I wanted to find the largest component of an orbit on a single axis, like finding where on the orbit a satellite would reach its highest X component (not specifically an apoapsis, just when the X value is at its highest) and I have all of the orbital elements provided, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you'd have to convert all orbital elements into their ECI counterparts and check those. Depending on your choice of programming language, you might find some functions to do the job. Matlab has one: https://in.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/keplerian2ijk.html